# how to use select (jdbc) with prepared statement using javafx

Tags: select, jdbc, javafx, prepared-statement

I have a jdbc code and I want to select my data from database using prepared statement and javaFX . I mean i want to use java fx to get the String part . here is my data access code ,But I dont know how to write the controller method with Parameters and how to iterate the list.

```
      public ArrayList selectByNameAndFamily(Person person) throws Exception {
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from person where name = ? and family = ?");
    preparedStatement.setString(1,person.getName());
    preparedStatement.setString(2,person.getFamily());
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        person.setPhone(resultSet.getLong("phone"));
        person.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
        person.setPlaque(resultSet.getLong("plaque"));
        person.setUnit(resultSet.getLong("unit"));
        person.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
        person.setFamily(resultSet.getString("family"));
        person.setAddress1(resultSet.getString("Address1"));
        person.setAddress2(resultSet.getString("address2"));
        person.setAddress3(resultSet.getString("address3"));

        list.add(person);
    }
    return list;
```

*note my table object name is Person and I already made object of PreparedStatement in my code .

Comment: "idk what should I write instead of `person.getName()`". What is the name of the person you are trying to select???

Comment: Add a counter into the while loop to check how many times it has entered and print it out to see what happens.There is more advanced ways but try that for the beggining. Or print out the size of the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this. Some of my methods and variables are different from yours. Also, I used SQLITE and created a sample database. This is not a javaFX problem, this is a java problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Person person = new Person();

        System.out.println("Enter person name: ");
        person.setName(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter person family: ");
        person.setFamilyName(input.nextLine());

        ArrayList<Person> peopleFromDatabase = selectByNameAndFamily(person);

        for(Person entry : peopleFromDatabase)
        {
             System.out.println("PERSON:");
             System.out.println("\t" + entry.getName());
             System.out.println("\t" + entry.getID());
             System.out.println("\t" + entry.getFamilyName());
             System.out.println("\t" + entry.getAddress1());

             System.out.println();
        }
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TestingGround.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Person> selectByNameAndFamily(Person person)
{
    ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList();
    String sql = "select * from person where name = ? and family_name = ?";

    try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:family.db");
        PreparedStatement prestmt = con.prepareStatement(sql); )
    {
        prestmt.setString(1, person.getName());
        prestmt.setString(2, person.getFamilyName());
        ResultSet rs = prestmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Person returningPerson = new Person();

            returningPerson.setID(rs.getLong("id"));
            returningPerson.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            returningPerson.setFamilyName(rs.getString("family_name"));
            returningPerson.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));                
            returningPerson.setPlaque(Long.parseLong(rs.getString("plaque")));
            returningPerson.setUnit(Long.parseLong(rs.getString("unit")));                
            returningPerson.setAddress1(rs.getString("Address1"));
            returningPerson.setAddress2(rs.getString("address2"));
            returningPerson.setAddress3(rs.getString("address3"));

            list.add(returningPerson);
        }


    }   
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TestingGround.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Are these two lines true? 

        
        preparedStatement.setString(1,person.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,person.getFamily());

Comment: I use the same code as you said, but in the end ,the out put is nothing .

Comment: Thank's it works fine . but there is still one problem for me . I want to use javaFX instead of Scanner to input name and family . what should i change ? I mean what should i write instead of this line 
          person.setName(input.nextLine());

Comment: You should read up on JavaFx and Java. JavaFx is pretty much an extension of Java. It is supposed to be an upgrade from Java Swing. It's GUI related. Scanner is not GUI related. Scanner is probably the best way to get information from the keyboard, so there is no need to look for anything different.

Comment: Also, if the answer is correct, you should mark it as correct.

Comment: I may have read your comment question incorrectly. You should open a new question. If I am now understanding it correctly, you should maybe create a textfield in javafx and get the text from that field using yourTextFieldName.getTextI() in the place of input.nextLine().

Answer (score 1):

After

```
Person person = new Person();
```

person.getName() and person.getFamily() will be what? null? empty string?

Therefore preparedStatement.executeQuery() will find no rows and you'll never enter

```
while (resultSet.next())
```